# RegistryKey.OpenSubKey() Not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, registry, win32-process

I want to get postrgeSQL installation and data directory path from the registry with the following code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\PostgreSQL\Installations");
foreach (var k in key.GetSubKeyNames())
{

}
```

However, that does not work for me, as

```
key.GetSubKeyNames()
```

says it is null. How can I solve that?

Comment: Well *does* that path definitely exist in your registry? Check everything about it *very* carefully. You might also want to run the code with admin privileges to see whether it's a permissions issue.

Comment: The standard mistake is to let your program run as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit version of Windows.  It will be redirected to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target settings.

Comment: exaclty, its a 32-bit app, running on 64-bit version of Windows. What I should do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Check your user access to the registry key.  If you don't have access your code will return null.  You can do this by running regedit, right clicking on the registry key and selecting "permissions".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AdrianHHH Looks like a reasonable possible answer to me.

Comment: im runnign the app as admin (runas verb)